No crea correctamente swagger.json
Realice la documentacion en 4 archivos (main, routes y 2 handler) que se encuentran en distintas carpertas, pero al ejecutar swag init no me crea correctamente el swagger, solo toma los datos del main.

Hola Matias, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte necesitamos ver tu código, solo la porción pertinente, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y lo agregues como texto.

Utilice el comando
swag init --parseDependency --parseInternal --parseDepth 1 -g main.go
que me decia que era lo que fallaba. Era porque estaba mal lo documentado.
